# IEnumerable interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, ienumerable

I don't understand why `IList` implements `IEnumerable` taking in consideration that `IList` implements `ICollection` that implements `IEnumerable` also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you want to know why it declares that it implements `ICollection` as well as `IEnumerable`, when the first implies the second. I suspect the main reason is clarity: it means people don't need to look back to `ICollection` to check that that already extends `IEnumerable`.

There are other times when you need to redeclare an interface implementation, if you want to re-implement an interface method which was previously explicitly implemented in a base class - but I don't think that's the reason in this case.

EDIT: I've been assuming that the source code that the docs are built from has the declaration including both interfaces. Another possible alternative is that *all* interfaces in the hierarchy are automatically pulled in by the doc generator. In which case the question becomes "why does the doc generator do that" - and the answer is almost certainly still "clarity".

Comment: +1 my gut is also telling me this is for clarity it is possible that this enables some reflection hacks that require a first level of inheritance

Comment: Since it is the interfaces (not the classes), re-implementation isn't really an issue.

Comment: I cant seem to find a way to get reflection to detect any difference, I think only the metadata interfaces know about this definition

Answer (score 8):

`IList` only implements `IEnumerable` by associaton; i.e. it implements `IEnumerable` precisely **because** it inherits `ICollection` which is `IEnumerable`. You'd get the same with type hierarchies (although only single inheritance:

```
class Enumerable {}
class Collection : Enumerable {}
class List : Collection {}
```

so `List` is an `Enumerable`; in the same way, `IList` is `IEnumerable`.

For example, if I write:

```
interface IA {}
interface IB : IA { }
interface IC : IB { }
```

And look at the metadata, then it appears that `IC : IA, IB` - but this is only indirect; here's the IL:

```
.class private interface abstract auto ansi IA
{
}
.class private interface abstract auto ansi IB
    implements IA
{
}
.class private interface abstract auto ansi IC
    implements IB, IA
{
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this just now, I do wish you'd have the courage to say why. I won't take it personally (unless, of course, it is purely a vendetta...)

Answer (score 1):

If you were to open the code in ReSharper, it would indicate that the `IEnumerable` interface declaration on `IList` wasn't required, as it is already specified via `ICollection`.